# Recursion issue in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

The Following Code:

```
(define (rcons val lst)
    (if (not (null? lst))
        (cons (car lst) (rcons val (cdr lst)))
        (cons lst (list val)))))

(rcons 'E '(A B C D))
```

Should produce `(A B C D E)` but instead gives a result of `(A B C D () E)`

What' wrong with my recursive step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't run this locally, but you should be returning the end of the list on the final recursion (and not the entire list like you're trying to do, which is always null there by the way...):

```
(define (rcons val lst)
    (if (not (null? lst))
        (cons (car lst) (rcons val (cdr lst)))
        (cons val '()))) ; recursion ends here - only return end of list cons
```

Remember proper lists end in null (`'()`).

### List structure:

What you get if you think of the recursion unfolding is (look at the **last** `cons`):

```
(cons #1 (cons #2 (cons #3 (cons .... (cons val '()))))
```

`#1`, `#2`, `#3` etc describe the members of the original `lst` as well as the frame number (1 being the first).

More visualising - the recursion unfolds:

```
; {x} - x marks frame as well as location in original 'lst'
; frame 1
(cons (car lst {1}) (rcons val (cdr lst)))
; frame 2
(cons (car lst {1}) (cons (car lst {2}) (rcons val (cdr lst))))
; frame 3 ...
(cons (car lst {1}) (cons (car lst {2}) (cons (car lst {3}) (rcons val (cdr lst)))))
```

If you look back at **List structure**, it's easy to see we want `val` to be the `car` of the last `cons`, and `'()` to be it's `cdr` - to form a proper list. This is **exactly** what I fixed in your code.

Comment: Can you briefly explain why we return the end of the list on the final recursion (and your solution works, thanks).

Comment: Can you give me some idea what's not clear? You were trying to end the list with `'() val` instead of `val '()`, which is a proper list. Also, `lst` is always null, if you take a close look - you actually veriifed it using `(null? lst)` in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are so close!

List structure is iterated from beginning to end and built from end to beginning. If you want to make the list `(1 2 3)` you first have to make `(2 3)` then `cons` the first `1` to the finished constructed list `(2 3)`. Your `rcons` do that as you see `(cons (car lst) (rcons val (cdr lst)))` which makes a list with the current value to the `rcons` of the rest of the list. The `cons` is done after both expressions has been evaluated. So for a 3 element list it will recurse 3 times. `(cons first-value (cons second-value (cons third-value (rcons val-value '()))))`

So if `val` is 4 `(rcons 4 '())` should produce `(cons 4 '())` or just `(list 4)` which is the same. This should work nicely.

```
(define (rcons val lst)
    (if (not (null? lst))
        (cons (car lst) (rcons val (cdr lst)))
        (list val)))

(rcons 4 '())      ; ==> (4)
(rcons 4 '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (1 2 3 4)
```